# When I minimize the browser window, the script stops. How fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Situation following: there is a one-window application (a game with spinning reels), which works good if the browser tab in which the application is running does not lose focus. But it is necessary to minimize the browser window (or switch to another tab), and then return back, then the app stops. And this happens not immediately, but over different periods of time (from some seconds to some minutes), and on the same cycle of rotation. Animations built using requestAnimationFrame().
How to solve this problem?

```
var lastTime = Date.now();
function main() {

  var now = Date.now();
  var dt = Math.min((now - lastTime), 20) / 1000.0;

  update(dt);
  render();
  lastTime = now;

  requestAnimationFrame(main);

}
```

Comment: Could you post the update function too? Do you have any error firing in the console?

Comment: I do not have errors in the console. Update function is too big.

Comment: but your error certainly comes from here, maybe something to do with `dt`. Try to narrow it until you find the problematic part. One hacky solution would be to check on document focus if the script still runs, and if not, relaunch it, but I highly recommend to find the buggy part as it is not normal behaviour.

Comment: Which browser/OS are you testing? Or does it happen with all browsers? Some browsers (on some devices) do _freeze_ script activity when the tab does not have focus - but this is by design (to curb battery consumption / memory usage) - in this case there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: @w3d, I think that for RAF it's even in the specs that browser have to freeze execution, but it should restart as soon as the page gets focus back.

Comment: I am testing in two browsers: Firefox and Chrome. Both behave the same.  "Restart as soon as the page gets focus back" - it is only an idea now.

Comment: @piast could you post your code into a pastebin please?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was resolved as follows: "requestAnimationFrame" replaced by the "setTimeout", which operates in the web-Worker (https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer)